# External CSS not always displaying

Tags: css

For some odd reason all my external CSS does work fine except for this one.  It does work if I add it internally to my html page but not if it is linked to the external sheet

in the external sheet

```
.title {
    font-size: 30px; 
    font-family: Bebas Neue, cursive;
}
```

but

```
<span class="title">hello</span>
```

does not work in the html sheet

tried with `. class=""` or even with `# id=""` but neither work
it would make sense to me if nothing else worked but I don't understand how just 1 can be giving me problems

Comment: If you really used a ` ` space character after the `.` in `. class=""` then that is the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you link your external `CSS` file?

Comment: the external stylesheet is linked, all the other CSS works,  there was no white space left between .title {} , I will add more code

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Internal StyleSheet :

```html
<span class="title"  style=" font-size: 30px;font-family: Bebas Neue, cursive;" >Hello </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

OMG! I figured out the issue!! I am an inexperienced coder and as with many issues I encounter, at the end it often is just something silly. The code actually worked but my browser was working on the cached version of the page so I was not seeing the changes. Once I CTRL-F5 rather than doing just a straight reload my CSS appeared!